# Join multiple datasets in Apache Spark using joinWith

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to join three datasets with `joinWith` and then process them in a nice way, like `case ((t1, t2), t3)) =>`, but it fails with an exception. The cause of the error is pretty clear. Result of joining two datasets this way gives:

```
+-------------+----------+
|           _1|        _2|
+-------------+----------+
|[1, Name1, 1]|[1, Dept1]|
|[2, Name2, 2]|[2, Dept2]|
|[3, Name3, 3]|[3, Dept3]|
+-------------+----------+
```

So I can't join the result table with subsequent table. Maybe there some other ways? Is it even possible to join multiple tables in "typesafe" way (using `joinWith`)?

Idea:

```scala
    object MainApp {

      case class Emp(empId: Int, name: String, deptId: Int)
      case class Dept(deptId: Int, name: String)
      case class Addr(empId: Int, name: String)

      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .master("local[*]")
          .appName("spark_test")
          .getOrCreate()

        import spark.implicits._

        val emps = Seq(
          (1, "Name1", 1),
          (2, "Name2", 2),
          (3, "Name3", 3)
        ).toDF("empId", "name", "deptId").as[Emp]

        val depts = Seq(
          (1, "Dept1"),
          (2, "Dept2"),
          (3, "Dept3")
        ).toDF("deptId", "name").as[Dept]

        val addrs = Seq(
          (1, "Addr1"),
          (2, "Addr2"),
          (3, "Addr3")
        ).toDF("empId", "name").as[Addr]

        val result = emps
          .joinWith(depts, emps("deptId") === depts("deptId"), "inner")
          .joinWith(addrs, emps("empId") === addrs("empId"), "inner")         

//        result.map {
//          case ((emps, depts), addrs) => ???
//        }
      }
    }
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) empId#7 missing from _1#41,_2#42,empId#34,name#35 in operator !Join Inner, (empId#7 = empId#34). Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: empId. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;;
!Join Inner, (empId#7 = empId#34)
:- Join Inner, (_1#41.deptId = _2#42.deptId)
:  :- Project [named_struct(empId, empId#7, name, name#8, deptId, deptId#9) AS _1#41]
:  :  +- Project [_1#3 AS empId#7, _2#4 AS name#8, _3#5 AS deptId#9]
:  :     +- LocalRelation [_1#3, _2#4, _3#5]
:  +- Project [named_struct(deptId, deptId#22, name, name#23) AS _2#42]
:     +- Project [_1#19 AS deptId#22, _2#20 AS name#23]
:        +- LocalRelation [_1#19, _2#20]
+- Project [_1#31 AS empId#34, _2#32 AS name#35]
   +- LocalRelation [_1#31, _2#32]

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.joinWith(Dataset.scala:1079)
    at sample.sample.MainApp$.main(MainApp.scala:41)
    at sample.sample.MainApp.main(MainApp.scala)
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You need to do it in 2 steps and use a map with a case as you started on*. So much for the new dataset API in this regard. The old could do an n-way JOIN.

Specifically, in contrast to a DF, the DS returns a Tuple of the two classes from the left and right Dataset when using `joinWith`. The function is defined as:

```
joinWith[U](other: Dataset[U], 
            condition: Column, 
            joinType: S): Dataset[(T,U)]
```

Clearly - from your output - it cannot work like the `join` API.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is possible to join using joinWith, but it's not very elegant. As the first join creates a tuple, you need to point to it somehow and you can do it with `$"_1.empId"`.

```scala
    val result = emps
      .joinWith(depts, emps("deptId") === depts("deptId"), "inner")
      .joinWith(addrs, $"_1.empId" === addrs("empId"), "inner")
```

To avoid creating the tuple you would have to first name the dataset and then perform the next joinWith.